# Remove minutes from @CreationTimestamp annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am using an annotation @CreationTimestamp to write a date when a file is uploaded. How can I remove the minutes to leave only the year, month and day?

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "exchange_rates")
public class ExchangeRate {

///

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "downloaddate")
    private Date downloaddate;
}
```

Comment: So you don't want a timestamp but rather just a date. Did you try using `java.time.LocalDate` instead of the _old_ `java.util.Date`? And why not keep the exact timestamp but only format it to a "date" when needed? Don't needlessly strip that information from the data but only strip it from output where needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)` to only store the date part.

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'

Comment: If i use this annotation i get this error

Comment: please also post what the root cause of this exception is (the last "caused by" part)